# Visual Basic Error - mysql client does not support authentication protocol - How do I fix?

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have an old VB6 program that uses MySQL 4 database.  Early this year my IS department switched to MySQL 5 and will not shut down MySQL 4 until I can connect to MySQL 5.  Unfortunately, I am not able to connect and get this VB error message:

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':

[TCX][MyODBC]Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client.

Here's the code I am using:

```
Private ADOCn As ADODB.Connection
Private adoRS As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim mstrConnString As String

   mstrConnString = "driver=MySQL;server=mysql5;database=engprogs;port=3310;UID=enguser;PWD=????????"

   Set ADOCn = New ADODB.Connection
   ADOCn.ConnectionString = mstrConnString
   ADOCn.Open mstrConnString

End Sub
```

This code works fine with MySQL 4 but fails with MySQL 5.

I downloaded and installed the MySQL Connector/C 6.1.6 but am still getting the same error as shown above.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You need Connector/ODBC, and you need to use a proper connection string ([1](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-1/), [2](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/)).

Comment: Thanks @GSerg,  I think this is what you were telling me to use: Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Port=3306;
Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;

Comment: If that is what I need then I don't know how I would use that with ADOCn.ConnectionString and then ADOCn.Open ???

Comment: If you haven't already looked at it, connectionstrings.com is a good resource. https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-oledb-mysqlprov/

Comment: @BobT You are already using a connection string (`mstrConnString `). Replace it with this one having installed the Connector/ODBC.

Comment: @GSerg is there a link you were offering in "Replace it with this one"?

Comment: @BobT Yes, in my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420097/visual-basic-error-mysql-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-how?noredirect=1#comment47012293_29420097), under numbers `1` and `2` in brackets.